# Best way to process and store real time MQTT data in AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, real-time-data

I need to receive the real-time MQTT data, get them stored in AWS Cloud, and provide the insights using these data in a separate web-based application.  In this requirement, would that be better to store them in DynamoDB or S3?

I tried to process the data using AWS IoT Core, Kinesis Data Stream, Lambda, and DynamoDB table. The data is getting processed, but I'm not sure whether all the data that I receive is getting stored or not. Because the first 150 records are processed and stored in DynamoDB at the normal speed, the processing time is getting slower post processing 150 records. Not sure what went wrong. So, I'm not sure whether my architecture is ok or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If your web application fetches data frequency, it may be better to store your data in DynamoDB instead of S3. However, you may also want to consider cost optimization of your DynamoDB storage by archiving the old, rarely accessed data to S3 periodically and setting time-to-live (TTL) to each DynamoDB item.

Regarding processing time, it may be caused by one or the combination of the following

- The DynamoDB uses provisioned capacity and does not have enough write capacity unit (WCU)
- The Kinesis Data Stream is on provisioned mode and the data stream throughput is throttled
- If you use Lambda for data processing, it may be caused by processing large data with limited memory, or code inside Lambda function is not optimized

If you do light processing, you can also simplify the service stack and see whether it improves the processing speed.

- IoT core -> IoT rule (SQL statement) -> rule action (DynamoDB) -> DynamoDB
- IoT core -> IoT rule -> rule action (Lambda) -> DynamoDB
- IoT core -> IoT rule (SQL statement) -> rule action (Lambda) -> DynamoDB

Comment: Thanks Dave. As of now, I'm using DynamoDB & Kinesis Data Stream as On Demand. Slowly I will move to Provisioned capacity later. Relaxing the memory inside the Lambda function helped really. Now I could see more data is getting processed, but now my question is how do I make sure I'm processing all the data without any data loss. For ex, If I receive 1000 MQTT messages per minute, then how do I make sure all those 1000 messages are getting processed and got stored in Dynamodb?

Comment: If all data reaches the IoT Core, it is unlikely to lose any of them if the partition key is guaranteed to be unique. For testing, you can add extra property to the MQTT payload temporarily, such as sequence number to inspect whether all data is processed and stored in DynamoDB. Or, you can also create a dedicated counter table in DynamoDB. Every time a payload is received by IoT Core, create a rule to increment the counter inside the counter table. Then compare the number of Lambda calls and the counter of DynamoDB table. Both should match to validate there is no data loss.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Partition keys are correct, so I don't find any issues with them. I introduced a couple of counters, one at the receiving end in IoT core and another one at the data ingestion end. I found few mismatches, I'm glad that I found a few duplicate entries (might be a bug from the external system that send the data) and these entries were not ingested into DynamoDB due to the Partition key constraints. Escalated this to the external system to dig this further from their end. Fingers crossed. Let's hear it from them